# One-step initialization of defaultdict that appends to list?

Tags: python, defaultdict

It would be convenient if a `defaultdict` could be initialized along the following lines

```
d = defaultdict(list, (('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('a', 2),
   ('b', 3)))
```

to produce

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1, 2], 'c': [3], 'b': [2, 3], 'd': [4]})
```

Instead, I get

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'b': 3, 'd': 4})
```

To get what I need, I end up having to do this:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for x, y in (('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)):
    d[x].append(y)
```

This is IMO one step more than should be necessary, am I missing something here?

Comment: How would it know to use append on the list? And what about other types?

Comment: @JonClements, good point. However one would think that `list` is a common-enough use case that a convenience method(perhaps a class-method) is justified?

Comment: Wouldn't this convenience method be pretty much exactly what you just wrote out at the end of your post? Why not wrap those three lines in a function and call it a day?

Comment: @1_CR: I would say that `defaultdict(list)` is super-common. But **initializing** that data structure in the manner you propose is... less so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the behavior you describe would not be consistent with the `defaultdict`s other behaviors.  Seems like what you want is `FooDict` such that

```
>>> f = FooDict()
>>> f['a'] = 1
>>> f['a'] = 2
>>> f['a']
[1, 2]
```

We can do that, but not with defaultdict; lets call it AppendDict

```
import collections

class AppendDict(collections.MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, container=list, append=None, pairs=()):
        self.container = collections.defaultdict(container)
        self.append = append or list.append
        for key, value in pairs:
            self[key] = value

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.append(self.container[key], value)

    def __getitem__(self, key): return self.container[key]
    def __delitem__(self, key): del self.container[key]
    def __iter__(self): return iter(self.container)
    def __len__(self): return len(self.container)
```

Answer (score 22):

What you're apparently missing is that `defaultdict` is a straightforward (not especially "magical") subclass of `dict`.  All the first argument does is provide a factory function for *missing* keys.  When you initialize a `defaultdict`, you're initializing a `dict`.

If you want to produce

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1, 2], 'c': [3], 'b': [2, 3], 'd': [4]})
```

you should be initializing it the way you would initialize any other `dict` whose values are lists:

```
d = defaultdict(list, (('a', [1, 2]), ('b', [2, 3]), ('c', [3]), ('d', [4])))
```

If your initial data has to be in the form of tuples whose 2nd element is always an integer, then just go with the `for` loop.  You call it one extra step; I call it the clear and obvious way to do it.

Comment: +1. BTW, initializing it as `defaultdict(list, {'a': [1, 2], 'c': [3], 'b': [2, 3], 'd': [4]})` also works.

Answer (score 4):

Sorting and `itertools.groupby` go a long way:

```
>>> L = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
>>> L.sort(key=lambda t:t[0])
>>> d = defaultdict(list, [(tup[0], [t[1] for t in tup[1]]) for tup in itertools.groupby(L, key=lambda t: t[0])])
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [1, 2], 'c': [3], 'b': [2, 3], 'd': [4]})
```

To make this more of a one-liner:

```
L = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
d = defaultdict(list, [(tup[0], [t[1] for t in tup[1]]) for tup in itertools.groupby(sorted(L, key=operator.itemgetter(0)), key=lambda t: t[0])])
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If the OP doesn't like a perfectly fine `for` loop, I doubt that `itertools.groupby`, a `sort`, a list comp, and either `lambda` or `itemgetter` is going to appeal..

Comment: Interesting. But note that the `sort` and the `groupby` end up doing all the leg-work here. so that you could just as easily feed the output from the `groupby` to a regular `dict` instead of a `defaultdict`!

Comment: @1_CR: You're right. But, I gave you a defaultdict because you asked for one.

Comment: What about performance, is it slower or faster if you make it all in one line?

Comment: @badc0re: I haven't run `timeit`s, but I suspect that `sorted` would be slower than `sort` (time for `malloc`); the list comprehension would be faster than the equivalent for loop (I `timeit`'d this a few years ago when I was interested in sort of thing), presumably because the interpreter is able to accurately predict the size of the list

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Given that Python almost always has more than enough free memory around to create a 5-element list (it starts off with a few hundred MB on most platforms, and keeps an even larger freelist if you go beyond that), I doubt there are any `malloc` costs at all.

Comment: @abarnert: (honest question) won't `malloc` for a list have a cost anyway, though? Won't this be avoided with `sort` (as opposed to `sorted`)? If you were talking about the list comprehension, I would have to use the scalability argument, as I /have/ observed 10x speedups with list comprehensions in the past

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: If you never call `malloc`, it doesn't have a cost. And that's the point; you almost never call `malloc`. (Of course you're right that a list comprehension is faster than an explicit loop around `append` or the like, because the core loop is happening in C instead of Python, a number of bits can be short-circuited, you can take advantage of the custom `LIST_APPEND` opcode, etc. But that's not what I was talking about.)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: It is true that `a.sort()` is usually faster than `sorted(a)`, but that usually has nothing to do with `malloc`; it's the fact that `sort` can rely on having a list, and that it can munge the list in-place, meaning it can use fast-indexing, swap and shift values directly, etc. For tiny and huge lists this doesn't help as much, but for mid-sized ones it can be an order of magnitude faster (to the point that people sometimes suggest that `sorted(x)` just do `list(x); x.sort(); return x`).

Comment: @abarnert: please explain that speedup on mid-sized lists some more. I always thought that a large factor of the speedup came from `sorted` having to malloc more space for the new copy of the list (since the core C code under python's hood would have to `malloc` for a new list, no?)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: I don't know how else to explain it, but I'll try. CPython has a custom allocator (actually more than one, but let's ignore that). When some higher-level code wants to create a new `list` object, or a new buffer for the array used by the `list`, it doesn't call `malloc`, it just asks the allocator. Usually this just means reusing a an object or buffer that was recently released, or was pre-allocated at startup. Of course the allocator _may_ be forced to call `malloc` (or something else) if it runs out of space, but it rarely has to.

Comment: @abarnert: dude that's awesome! I'd love for you to chime in on [this question I just posted as a result of this conversation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18522574/198633)

Answer (score 3):

I think most of this is a lot of smoke and mirrors to avoid a simple [for](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) loop:

```
di={}
for k,v in [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('a', 2),('b', 3)]:
    di.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)
# di={'a': [1, 2], 'c': [3], 'b': [2, 3], 'd': [4]}
```

If your goal is one line and you want abusive syntax that I cannot at all endorse or support you can use a side effect comprehension:

```
>>> li=[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('a', 2),('b', 3)]
>>> di={};{di.setdefault(k[0],[]).append(k[1]) for k in li}
set([None])
>>> di
{'a': [1, 2], 'c': [3], 'b': [2, 3], 'd': [4]}
```

If you *really* want to go overboard into the unreadable:

```
>>> {k1:[e for _,e in v1] for k1,v1 in {k:filter(lambda x: x[0]==k,li) for k,v in li}.items()}
{'a': [1, 2], 'c': [3], 'b': [2, 3], 'd': [4]}
```

You don't want to do that. Use the for loop Luke!

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> kvs = [(1,2), (2,3), (1,3)]
>>> reduce(
...   lambda d,(k,v): d[k].append(v) or d,
...   kvs,
...   defaultdict(list))
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [2, 3], 2: [3]})
```

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax