# CPython: Is there any way to traverse a PyObject as a sequence without having to create and destroy objects subsequently?

Tags: python, cpython

To make a PyObject that acts as a sequence, I just added a fuction to the slot `sq_item` of the variable `tp_as_sequence` of a `PyTypeObject`.

Here is my `sq_item` function:

```
static PyObject *py_myseq__sq_item(PyMySeq *self, unsigned int keynum)
{
    if (keynum < 0) keynum += self->len; /* ex.:>>> my_seq[-1] */
    if (keynum >= 0 && keynum < self->len) {
        MyItem *item = &self->items[keynum];

        return PyMyItem_New(item);
    }

    PyErr_Format(PyExc_IndexError,
                 "PyMySeq[index]: index %d out of range", keynum);
    return NULL;
}
```

Every time I want to get a item of the sequence, the `PyMyItem_New` function is called. This is good in most cases. But to cases like when using a for loop this is quite inefficient:

```
for i in myPyObjSeq:
    print(i)
```

If my sequence has one million items. The items will be created and destroyed 1 million times in this loop!!!

The question is: Is there any way to avoid this???

Comment: What is `PyMyItem_New`? Is your sequence already a python object? If not, yeah, you need to create a million of them. Consider `numpy` for example. It implements bulk operations in C but if you do operations in python, the performance drops dramatically because it needs to "pythonize" its C arrays much like you have to.

Comment: `PyMyItem_New` Is the function that transforms a item of the sequence into a PyObject. The Sequence has the variable `* items` and each item is of type `struct MyItem`.

Comment: If you don't already have a million Python objects representing your sequence items, you'll have to make them. You can try to optimize the allocations involved by keeping a free list or something, but you can't avoid needing to create objects.

Comment: Of course, maybe you don't need a `for` loop at all. If you can avoid the Python-level iteration entirely and do all the work in C, you don't need to make Python objects. (This is one of the reasons we try to avoid `for` loops in NumPy.)

Comment: Consider that `print(i)` also creates objects (e.g., the string created when your code converts `i` to a string and any intermediate objects created in the print function itself). In this example you could write a method on your sequence object that takes an index and prints its C-calculated C value. Generally, have the sequence implement expensive operations

Comment: @user2357112, I can not avoid using for, because each item will be configured by the user :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

- First of all, in CPython API, allocating and freeing many small objects is common. CPython has an allocator optimized for this, so its generally not something to avoid.
  [See this question for details.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522574/cpython-memory-allocation)
- If you need to loop over millions of items, you might want to consider implementing an iterator, so you can loop over items but never allocate all at once.
- Another option, *(which isn't so Pythonic)* - is to have a method on your sequence that takes a callable. Similar to how you can pass a callback to  `list.sort(key=function)`.
  In this case you could pass the same object to each function, with a modified *index*.
  But don't be fooled, calling a function create's PyObject's too!
- If the data is primitive C structures, you could expose using the buffer interface, see memory-views too.
- You could always have a single Python object which is modified in-place, but this will cause users of your API some confusion since they may access an index and not realize further access will change the other variable *(bad practice, don't do this`)*