# Append to list in python dict comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Suppose we have a dictionary `inp = {"virat":60,"rohit":50,"sardhul":50,"rana":60}` and
we should get the output as `{60: ['virat', 'rana'], 50: ['rohit', 'sardhul']}`

I can do it in normal python programming as follows

```
    out = dict()
    for key, val in inp.items():
        if val not in out:
            out[val] = [key]
        else:
            out[val].append(key)
```

The output is `{60: ['virat', 'rana'], 50: ['rohit', 'sardhul']}`

How can we do the same in dictionary comprehension?

Comment: a solution as a comprehension would not be efficient in this case, why this constraint?

Comment: You could use `collections.defaultdict` though so you won't need the `if` `else`.

Comment: [It is possible but extremely ugly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18520982/10166393)

Answer (score 4):

A more sophisticated way to do it:

```
out = {}
for key, val in inp.items():
    out.setdefault(val, []).append(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, it is not efficient but if you MUST have a comprehension:

```
{ val: [ key for key,vv in inp.items() if vv == val ] for val in inp.values() }
```

This is basically equivalent to:

```
out = dict()
for val in inp.value():
    tmp = list()
    for key,vv in inp.items():
        if vv == val:
            tmp.append(key)
    out[val] = tmp
```

... which is a lot less efficient than your original code.